# Return sizeof a struct containing members ordered like given template parameters

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++14, template-meta-programming

```
template<typename... T>
constexpr std::size_t sizeof_struct()
{
    // Helper
    auto alignto = [](auto x, auto a) { return (x + a - 1) / a * a; };
    // Algorithm
    std::size_t max_align{0};
    std::array<std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>, sizeof...(T)> arr{{
        {alignof(T), sizeof(T)}...
        }};
    auto sum = std::accumulate(
        std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), std::size_t{0},
        [&max_align, alignto] (auto s, auto&& it) {
            max_align = std::max(it.first, max_align);
            return alignto(s, it.first) + it.second;
        });
    return max_align ? alignto(sum, max_align) : 1;
}
```

Is there any type I can put in the parameter pack `T...` that can break this code?  Anything else that doesn't look right?  Anything I can clean or make more concise?

Comment: If one were to assume that a recursively defined struct `struct S1 { T1 e1 }; struct S2 { S1 e1; T2 e2; };` has the same layout as `struct S2 { T1 e1; T2 e2 };` then you could use that in a simpler, C++11 solution. I don't have an inkling whether such an equivalency is mandated by the standard, or even whether it holds in practice...

Comment: @Kuba that's a wonderful idea, I'm going to see if I can find a guarantee saying it's always true.

Comment: @Kuba it seems to works for POD types, but not for more complicated classes with [virtual nonsense in particular](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/909b73fb0140b0e3).

Comment: Of course, when a derived class has virtual members, it will, on everyday implementations, have to hold a virtual table pointer. That's why it's bigger than the data elements themselves would suggest. But this whole thing is about classes that hold data only. You'd actually need to revert to a recursively defined struct that has virtual methods and/or virtual inheritance to get the correct size for such a struct.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks reasonable to me.

I don't understand why you keep `sum.first` and `sum.second` as separate values; IIUC, `sum.first` is "the size of the struct so far, minus its last element", and `sum.second` is "the size of the last element". It seems like you could just keep "the size of the struct so far" as a single value. That is, isn't your code equivalent to the following?

```
template<typename... T>
constexpr std::size_t sizeof_struct()
{
    using meta_t = std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>;
    auto alignto = [](auto x, auto a) { return (x + a - 1) / a * a; };
    size_t sum{0};
    std::size_t max_align{0};
    std::array<meta_t, sizeof...(T)> arr{{ {alignof(T), sizeof(T)}... }};
    for (auto&& it : arr) {
        sum = alignto(sum, it.first) + it.second;
        max_align = std::max(it.first, max_align);
    }
    return sum ? alignto(sum, max_align) : 1;
}
```

Or if not, why not?

---

In the above version I also "corrected" your brace placement on the `std::array` initializer; I think it's more idiomatic (and in this case specifically, more readable) to bundle together the outer pair of braces `{{ {x}... }}` as opposed to staggering them out as
 `{ {{x}...} }`.

Also `for (x : y)` is more idiomatic than `for (x: y)`, and you had a trailing redundant semicolon on the for-loop's body.

---

If you're looking for template type parameters that *break* the above code, try `sizeof_struct<char&>`. Your code returns `1`, but obviously it should return `sizeof(char*)`. You can solve that easily, though.

---

And of course you have no guarantee that the compiler's struct layout algorithm is equivalent to the one you've written. It almost certainly *is* (modulo base classes, vptrs, bitfields, and most importantly the fact that the compiler can reorder public and private data members)... but technically you have no portable way to know that.

Comment: Ah yeah, I had kept it there because I wanted to use `std::accumulate` originally instead of a bare for loop.  I realized that it'd be clearer to write the loop while tracking the max alignment as well, though.  Thanks for pointing out the cleaning opportunity, that looks much better.
And aw, I didn't realize `for ( : )` was idiomatic.  I always preferred my syntax but I don't mind changing it now that I know for sure there's an idiom.  And ah nice catch.  I'll try to convert references to pointers before passing them through to the function.  Thanks!

Comment: @BrianRodriguez I wouldn't bother about the idiomacity of `for (a: b)` vs. `for (a : b)`. I've seen both often enough and neither is less readable or makes less sense. It's only a matter of style.

Comment: I ended up replacing the whole loop with a `std::accumulate`, since I like using the STL as much as possible.  Aside from the  reference template conversion, I feel much better about the code.  Thank you!